# Warning on certificate keyUsage

Tags: ssl, certificate, digital-signature, mmc

I have created a certificate using MMC console and assigned it to a website. However, when I view the certificate there is a warning icon on the KeyUsage part. You can see this in the below screenshot:

[image]

Also, I'm getting error in one of the applications that - **KeyUsage does not allow digital signatures**.

Why is the Microsoft certificate tool warning on keyUsage? What is wrong with it or what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That icon is used to represent a certificate extension that is marked as "critical", it doesn't mean that there's something wrong with it. https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a92/what-is-the-caution-symbol-next-to-the-extension-name.aspx.

Critical extensions a perfectly normal. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3 says that for Key Usage:

> When present, conforming CAs SHOULD mark this extension as critical.

Comment: The above link is broken, but this post says the same thing: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/84eaa61f-d13b-4544-9185-078c014ab552/yellow-warning-signs-on-keyusage-in-detailed-certificate-display?forum=winserversecurity